# C++. название класса из строки

Tags: c++

```
#pragma once
#include "World\TileObject.h"
#include <memory>
#include "World\Dungeon_Floor_1.h"
class Cell
    //участок на уровне (базовый тайл (пол, стена итп), на котором лежат предметы и имеет координаты итп)
{private:
    unsigned int x_coord, y_coord;
    TileObject* _baseTile; //основной тайл клетки - пол, стена, вода итп

public:
    Cell(unsigned int x, unsigned int y, const std::string& objectname);
    ~Cell();
    Cell(const Cell &obj);
    void draw(sf::RenderTarget & window);
};
/////////////////////////////////////////////////
#include "Cell.h"

Cell::Cell(unsigned int x, unsigned int y, const std::string& objectname): x_coord(x), y_coord(y)
{
    if (objectname == "Dungeon_Floor_1") {

        _baseTile = new Dungeon_Floor_1();
    }

}


Cell::~Cell()
{
    delete _baseTile;
}

Cell::Cell(const Cell & obj)
{   x_coord = obj.x_coord;
    y_coord = obj.y_coord;
    _baseTile = obj._baseTile;}
```

Вот здесь

```
if (objectname == "Dungeon_Floor_1") {    
            _baseTile = new Dungeon_Floor_1();
        }
```

создается объект, отвечающий за определенный объект в игре через полиморфизм базового объекта. Это просто тест, можно ли мне как-нибудь преобразовывать строку "Dungeon_Floor_1"(которая в проверке) в название класса (new Dungeon_Floor_1()), чтобы избавиться от проверок, так как таких разных классов как Dungeon_Floor_1 будет мильон?

Answer (score 1):

Допустим у вас есть  классы

```
class  TileObject  {...};
class D_F_1 : public  TileObject {...};
class D_F_2 : public   TileObject {...};
class D_F_3 : public   D_F_2  {...};
...
```

тогда создайте таблицу обьектов с их именами

```
std::unordered_map<string, TileObject*> table;
    table["D_F_1"] = new D_F_1;
    table["D_F_2"] = new D_F_2;
    table["D_F_3"] = new D_F_3;
 ...
```

тогда вы можете записать

```
 _baseTile = table[objectname];
```

вместо:

```
  if (objectname == "Dungeon_Floor_1") {

        _baseTile = new Dungeon_Floor_1();
    }
```

Comment: Так получается тоже самое, только еще больше сущностей разводить в коде

Comment: @gmax007, не то же самое,это избавляет вас от проверок, что и вам нужно было, во вторых сущность добавляется только одна, а именно обьект  table